# Align in a straight row of DOM elements using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap now for my design, earlier I used table, tr and td and it worked fine. But now, the design gets changed and I want to see both elements in a single row.

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


jsfiddle is here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Z4ntn/438/

On top of it I would like to build similar kind in another rows.

Plz let me know what went wrong and what needs to be updated to see both in a single row.

Comment: make it display `inline-block or inline`

Comment: try this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap says `form-inline` for elements in same line

like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>

     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Bootply: 
[Form-inline](http://www.bootply.com/6Eblkip9yB)

Comment: Nice answer. :)

Comment: OK.. I got it now.. But, when I have two rows, the rows are very very near, if I use <br/> it makes a large gap difference, can we use any bootstrap class to keep little gap between two rows. Please let me know.  try to add one more same block and see.